# How to use four type image on checkbox in android

Tags: android, checkbox

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:state_checked="true" android:state_focused="true"
android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_checked_pressed" />
<item android:state_checked="false" android:state_focused="true"
android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_pressed" />
<item android:state_checked="false"
android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_normal" />
<item android:state_checked="true"
android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_checked" />
</selector>
```

This is my xml drawable.
how to use check box state with all four images.
please kindly help me what's wrong with this any help in this regard is greatly appreciated. Thanks.